# linear optimization of a minigrid

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, energy

l'm having trouble coding an optimization problem in pyomo.

I have a load profile , battery system , PV , and wind system.

My objective is to minimize the cost of the system.

P1- Wind power to load
P2- PV power to load
P3-Wind power to battery
P4-PV power to battery
P5-Battery power to load
SOC -state of charge

Objective
minimize costs (P3+P4+P5)(capital cost + operating expenses)

Constrains
p1(t)+p2(t)+p(5)=PL(t)
The power demanded by the load is always delivered
p1(t)+ p3(t)=<PW(t)
The power supplied to the load by the wind cannot exceed its capacity
p2(t)+ p4(t)=<PW(t)
The power supplied to the load by the PV cannot exceed its capacity

SOC min =<SOC(t)=<SOC max
The state of charge of a battery cannot exceed its limits

SOC(t)=S0C(t-1)+P3(t)+P4(t)-p5(t)

The state of charge at time is given by the above.

How can l optimize this problem in PYOMO.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  It is customary to post your effort (code) with a specific question rather than a blanket, "who can code this for me?" question.  There are many examples of functioning pyomo models on this site, and several that are electric grid related.  Do a little research, give it a try & repost if you are stuck.